# How to schedule something more frequently than every 10 minutes on Heroku?

Tags: heroku

This is pretty simple to ask, but harder to solve. The heroku scheduler addon allows for a frequency of every 10 min. But how can I retrieve data from an API every, say, 30 seconds?

I've looked into

- Whether the heroku scheduler can be tricked into doing it more frequently

  - Can't see a way
- Whether I can schedule so many of the same task that at least one is *bound* to run every 30 seconds

  - This is incredibly unproductive and imprecise, but it's the leading candidate for what I need to do
- App layer libraries, like ruby's `whenever` gem, which won't work on heroku because of some issues with cron/persistence of dynos
- Running an infinite loop at app startup - this works, but typically crashes after about 4-8 hours, and I don't know how to get it to start up again without me doing so manually.

#### Question

How can I reliably run a task every 30 seconds on heroku?

A side note:

- I need something that works in multiple languages, for example, ***both*** rails and node at the least

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try the [clockwork gem](https://github.com/Rykian/clockwork).

I've been using it on Heroku for a while now and it can run a task every 30 seconds (even less). The only downside of the gem is that you need to have a specific Dyno that runs the scheduler on your application.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [arask](https://github.com/Ebbe/arask). It works in Heroku and is simple to setup.

```
arask.create task: 'my:awesome_task', interval: 30.seconds
```